# Javascript toggle hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm learning javascript and I'm trying to toggle a simple hide and reveal effect to no luck. Currently the effect is only cancelled by clicking on another div with the same reference.

Here's my javascript:

```
var $ = jQuery;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section').hide(); 
});

function showMe(num){
    $('.section').hide(0);   
    $('#div_one'+num).fadeIn(1000); 

}
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.height-auto

{
    height:auto;
}
.section

{
    width:552px;
    min-height:300px;

}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
    <div class="section home-things visible" id="div_one1">

        <div class="section-contents"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like for "javascript:showMe(1)" to toggle "div_one1" and so forth.

Please help

Comment: First a quick side note: putting a `div` inside an `a` is invalid HTML and can cause problems in some browsers; use a `span` - you can still style it `display:block;` if needed, but it won't cause the issues in question anymore (or just style the `a` tag as such and drop the inner element altogether)

Comment: @CollinGrady Fyi you can have block elements inside anchor tag from html5 onwards. It is still a valid html.

Comment: Good to know; valid HTML5 then, but invalid everything else, so it depends on which he's using :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as written is purely a show function. You hide it every call of `showMe`, then show it afterwards.

Something like the following could make it an actual toggle:

```
function showMe(num)
{
    if ($('#div_one'+num).is(":visible"))
    { // the div is visible, so we just want to hide it
        $('#div_one'+num).hide();
    }
    else
    { // the div is not visible, so hide the rest and show it
        $('.section').hide(0);
        $('#div_one'+num).fadeIn(1000);
    }

    // I don't know what these next two lines are for,
    // as your code sample doesn't include them, so leaving as-is :)
    $('.height-auto').removeClass('height-auto');
    $('#strict').addClass('height-auto');
}
```

However, jQuery has some handy built-in functions that can make it a bit shorter:

```
function showMe(num)
{
    $('#div_one'+num).siblings('.section').hide();
    $('#div_one'+num).fadeToggle();

    // I don't know what these next two lines are for,
    // as your code sample doesn't include them, so leaving as-is :)
    $('.height-auto').removeClass('height-auto');
    $('#strict').addClass('height-auto');
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kxcau/)

Comment: Boom! Very concise and to the point. Thank you! I'll keep this in my notes

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but built it for you so just posting as an answer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.section').hide(); 
    $('#div_one1').show();
});

function showMe(num){
    $('.section').hide();
    $('#div_one'+num).fadeIn(300); 
}
```

[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/nmBQ7/2/)

Comment: This won't toggle things; it will still only show the section, not hide it again :)

Comment: This is exactly what `OP` wanted, `IMO` and it's toggling divs (one hide and another show).

Comment: @CollinGrady, BTW, did you check the demo ?

Comment: Also, logically one `div` always should be visible.